# Rails 4 Coffee Function Not Working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I'm adding few bells and whistles to my app's frontend so I'm going with coffee script.

I have a controller called "foo" and I see a file called "foo.coffee"

**javascripts/foo.coffee:**

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
  $("#bar").click ->
    alert "Click"
```

**views/foo/show.html.erb:**

```
<%= link_to "Get Foobar!", '#', id: "bar", class: 'button' %>
```

**Working js in application.js:**

```
$("#bar").on("click", function(){
      alert('Hey Foo!');
    });
```

When I click the button, no alert; nothing in console. If I change the code to pure js, I get the alert. I have `coffee-rails` in my Gemfile. Is there something missing? Im on rails 4.2.4

Comment: Show your working JS

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have updated the post.

Comment: These two snippets don't do the same thing, you see?

Comment: Is not that how you write in coffee script?

Comment: Try using `.on` syntax for CS too. Just to be sure.

Comment: Does JS version have that `page:change` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of potentialities you *may* have an issue with.

Firstly, you're using `page:change` - this is a [*turbolinks* hook](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) which is essentially the stand-in for `$(document).ready(....`

[image]

Whilst this is not an issue in itself, I think your use of it may curtail some of the functionality in your app:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/foo.coffee
foo = ->
   $("#bar").on "click", ->
      alert "Click"

$(document).on "ready page:load", foo
```

The above is more along the correct way to use this type of functionality. Another would be to use [`delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) from the `document` object for your `click`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/foo.coffee
$(document).on "click", "#bar", ->
   alert "Click"
```

Both of these methods should work to give you the functionality required. Specifically, they'll work with *Turbolinks* to ensure it does not impede functionality.

--

The main issue you have is likely that `foo.coffee` is not being loaded.

You need to ensure that you have the following in your `application.js`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
// require_tree .
```

This will make sure all your controller JS is being called when your application runs.

Comment: I have tubolinks commented out because I use stripe. I also have the `require_tree.`. I'll try some of the page events and report back later but I'm confident your answer should work.

Comment: If you have Turbolinks commented out, use the `$(document).on "click", "#bar"` and it should work

Comment: Had to pull out my laptop in the store lol. Works like a breeze. Thanks!!